# Chaining methods and pass the result for the next chain function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, method-chaining

I have this example piece of code:

```js
let test = {

  result: '',

  bolder: function (str = this.result) {
    this.result = '<b>' + str + '</b';
    return test;
  },

  italic: function (str = this.result) {
    this.result = '<i>' + this.result + '</i';
    return test;
  },
}

console.log(
  test.bolder('text').italic()
)

/*
RESULT: 
{
  result: '<i><b>text</b</i',
  bolder: [Function: bolder],
  italic: [Function: italic]
}

EXPECTED:
'<i><b>text</b</i'
*/
```

Where i pass a string in 'bolder' function, add some wrapping text (the return needs to be like '< b >text< / b >') and then i need the result to be passed to next chained function 'italic', so it can take the '< b >text< / b >' and append more things, like '< i > < b >text< / b > < / i >', then return this new value to the next function, and so on. If no value is passed as parameters, then i presume that i need to format the value in 'result', so it is the default value.

But the problem is: When i try to log the value if returns the whole object 'test', with all functions and stuff, not the formatted string '< i > < b >text< / b > < / i >'.

How can i achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) is the way to go.

You can call it explicitly but its advantage is that it is automatically called when you cast it to a string, as in Java or C#.

```js
let test = {
    result: '',

    bolder: function (str = this.result) {
        this.result = '<b>' + str + '</b>';
        return this;
    },

    italic: function (str = this.result) {
        this.result = '<i>' + this.result + '</i>';
        return this;
    },

    toString: function () {
        return this.result;
    }
};

console.log("" + test.bolder('text').italic());

// oh and from ES6, you can use template literals
// see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals
console.log(`use with template literal: ${test.bolder('text').italic()}`);
```

Comment: This work for me, thanks! but do you know if it has some side effects or sort of? I'm building a reusable lib for handling strings, concatenating pieces of other strings, just like the example, but I dont know what overriding the toString may cause.

Comment: @GustavoOliveira The side effect is precisely that you change the way your object is serialized into a string. You are the one that can determine if the is a case where it might be unwanted but in my opinion and from my experience there should be no problem. and it will make the things easier.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, It was really helpful!

Answer (score 2):

You need a final call to get the result, maybe with an own `toString` method.

```js
let test = {
    result: '',

    bolder: function (str = this.result) {
        this.result = '<b>' + str + '</b>';
        return this;
    },

    italic: function (str = this.result) {
        this.result = '<i>' + this.result + '</i>';
        return this;
    },

    toString: function () {
        return this.result;
    }
};

console.log(test.bolder('text').italic().toString());
```

Comment: And if I wanted to call the toString by default at the end of chain without call it explicitly ? It is possible ?

Comment: then you can not chain in random order.

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning your result to a property called `result` - Just access that property at the end of your function calls

You were also missing the closing `>` in your functions

```js
let test = {
  result: '',

  bolder: function (str = this.result) {
    this.result = '<b>' + str + '</b>';
    return test;
  },

  italic: function (str = this.result) {
    this.result = '<i>' + this.result + '</i>';
    return test;
  },
}

console.log(test.bolder('text').italic().result)
```

Comment: And if I want the '.result' to be called by default by the last chain function ? I know that I can just access the result, but I want something more clean and intuitive.

Comment: Not sure to be honest